# Rolling back a model after failed delete doesn’t update view

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to catch and handle a failed delete request by rolling back the model and having it remain in the view, but I'm having problems. I've got the following in my controller's *delete* action:

```
model.delete();

model.save().then(function() {

  alert('Deleted!');

}, function(err) {

  alert('Delete failed...');
  model.rollback();

});
```

This seems to work fine, I can see that the model quickly disappears from the store and then is instantly added back in, however the problem is that it just doesn't reappear in the view.

Both before and after the delete/rollback the model has the following properties

```
isLoaded:true
isDirty: false
isSaving: false
isDeleted: false
isError: false
isNew: false
isValid: true
```

My template is as follows:

```
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Number</th>
    <th>Speed Dial</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

  {{#each contact in model}}

    {{phonebook-row data=contact}}

  {{/each}}

</tbody>

</table>
```

Finally, here's the model hook in the respective route.

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({

  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('phonebook', { pageSize: 200 });
  }

});
```

I'm on Ember 1.11.1 and Ember Data 1.0.0-beta.16.1

Is this expected behaviour, or am I missing something? Any info would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried using an ember component?

Comment: What does your view look like?

Comment: @GJK No view, but added my template to the original question

Comment: One more thing: can you post the `model` hook for the relevant route?

Comment: @GJK just added that now, cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my best *guess* based on what I know about Ember Data:

Your model for this route is an array of records. Specifically, it's probably some subclass of [RecordArray](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RecordArray.html). The `RecordArray` likely handles a few things for you, like removing a record from the array when it's deleted. (Ember Data is known to do this elsewhere, like with [FilteredRecordArray](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.FilteredRecordArray.html).) My guess is that Ember Data is smart enough to remove the record from the array when you delete it, but not smart enough to add it back to the array when you roll it back.

As for how to fix it, I'm not 100% sure. :/ After your `model.rollback()` call, maybe try calling `model.reload()`. It's not so much a solution as a workaround, but it could get you through temporarily. In the meantime, I'm going to try to reproduce this issue and see if it's a bug in Ember Data.

Comment: That sounds like that's probably the case, but I just can't figure out how to actually make it update the view. I've tried a .reload() after the rollback but doesn't seem to have any effect unfortunately.

Comment: Honestly this is one of the 3 reasons I left ember-data back in 2014 (constant issues trying to keep the client data in a state I can reason about). If you are not heavily invested in ember-data you could look at alternatives that also support dirty tracking/rollback (that have much less pain/production bugs). Here is one I wrote and my team has had a great amount of production success with https://github.com/toranb/ember-cli-simple-store